# Loading WordPress Tries to Download a File

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress site is downloading file while trying to load any page (even wp-admin ) in browser.

Php- 7.1

After reading solutions from other forums deleted .htaccess file but no success.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening due to the missing modules required for your php. Assuming you have php7 installed, search available php7 modules using

```
sudo apt-cache search php7-*
```

Above command will list all available PHP7 modules for installation. You can begin installation of modules like,

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.1 php7.1-mysql php7.1-curl php7.1-json
```